# Mink does not switch back sessions?

Tags: php, drupal-8, mink

```
$driver = clone $this->mink->getSession()->getDriver();
$driver->reset();
$this->mink->registerSession('new', new Session($driver));
$this->mink->setDefaultSessionName('new');
// Do things.

// Switch back to the original.
$this->mink->setDefaultSessionName('default');
```

Well, it didn't switch back, my passing test became a failing one. As you can [see](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21simpletest%21src%21BrowserTestBase.php/function/BrowserTestBase%3A%3AinitMink/8.0.x) the session name originally was `default`. (This is not Drupal specific at all so it doesn't really belong on drupal SE.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `$this->mink->getSession()->getDriver()`

Use new driver with:

`$session = new Session(new GoutteDriver());
 $this->getMink()->registerSession('new', $session);`